# Repeat a song in afplay

Tags: audio, command-line

I am using `afplay` to play a song and I want it to be repeat. Is it possible just using `afplay`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop it in cycle:

In terminal:

```
while :; do afplay /path/to/song.mp3; done
```

Comment: there is a highly annoying pause at the end of each loop

Answer (score 0):

Expanding what @user3439968 said, if you use the fish shell, you can loop like this:

```
while true; afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Ping.aiff; end
```